# Why do some poeple claim, that choice of the working correlation in GEE doesn't affect the marginal coefficients?

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix, generalized-estimating-equations

I found this discussion:
[GEE: choosing proper working correlation structure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83577/gee-choosing-proper-working-correlation-structure)

Cite:

> Correlation structure in GEE, unlike mixed models, does not affect the
> marginal parameter estimates (which you are estimating with GEE). It
> does affect the standard error estimates though. This is independent
> of any link function. The link function in the GEE is for the marginal
> model.

and also:
[Do GEE and GLM estimate the same coefficients?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386443/do-gee-and-glm-estimate-the-same-coefficients)

> Yes. GEE and GLM will indeed have the same coefficients, but different
> standard errors. T

How can this be true, if:
[GEE with exchangeable working covariance  vs. assuming independence and using Huber-White standard errors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32584/gee-with-exchangeable-working-covariance-vs-assuming-independence-and-using-hu)

> In general, the GEE model solves the equation
>
> ∑i=1n∂μi∂βV(α)−1(yi−μi)=0
>
> as a function of the regression coefficients, β , where μi=xiβ is the
> expected values of the cluster i response, yi, given the predictors xi
> under the specified model. V(α)−1 is the "working" covariance matrix
> of the of the elements of cluster i. (note that μi=xiβ because we're
> dealing with a linear model but GEEs can more generally use a link
> function so that μi=g(xiβ))
>
> A key point here is that when you change the working covariance, you
> change the estimating equation, therefore the β that solves it will be
> different. For example, if V was σ2 down the diagonal and 0 off the
> diagonal and μi=xiβ as it does here, then the GEE estimator is the
> least squares estimator, which will not solve that equation in the
> exchangeable case. So it is no surprise that you're getting different
> parameter estimates. It may be a coincidence that you're getting the
> same standard errors.

So 1) the choice of the correlation structure changes the estimating equations and the resulting beta coefficients, 2) since B depends on the correlation structure, how can it do what the GLM does, if in GLM the choice is not present?

I just run an example in R and it clearly looks like the covariance structure DOES affect the betas:

```
> fm4 <- gee(Reaction ~ Days, id = Subject,data = sleepstudy,corstr = "AR-M", Mv=1)
Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
running glm to get initial regression estimate
(Intercept)        Days 
      251.4        10.5 
> coef(summary(fm4))
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)    253.5      10.71   23.67        6.36    39.88
Days            10.5       1.67    6.25        1.44     7.27


> fm4 <- gee(Reaction ~ Days, id = Subject,data = sleepstudy,corstr = "independence")
Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
running glm to get initial regression estimate
(Intercept)        Days 
      251.4        10.5 
> coef(summary(fm4))
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)    251.4       6.61   38.03        6.63    37.91
Days            10.5       1.24    8.45        1.50     6.97
```

The warning below only confirms that.

```
> fm4 <- gee(Reaction ~ Days, id = Subject,data = sleepstudy,corstr = "unstructured")
Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
running glm to get initial regression estimate
(Intercept)        Days 
      251.4        10.5 
Komunikat ostrzegawczy:
W poleceniu 'gee(Reaction ~ Days, id = Subject, data = sleepstudy, corstr = "unstructured")':
  Working correlation estimate not positive definite
> coef(summary(fm4))
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)   252.04       7.33   34.40       10.09    24.97
Days            9.78       1.02    9.62        2.64     3.71
```